# what is wrong with below sql update query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to run the following query

```
update IGNORE cs 
    set Value = '20934820843'
from admin.ConfigSupplemental as cs,      
    admin.Config as cc
where cs.ConsoleConfigID = cc.ID 
     and cs.Name = 'GetTime' and cc.Ctid = 200
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near ConfigSupplemental as cs

I also tried the below as well but I get the same error.

```
update IGNORE cs
   set cs.Value = '2039482094380'
from admin.ConfigSupplemental cs
   join admin.Config cc on 
   cc.ID = cs.ConsoleConfigID
where cs.Name = "GetTime"
   and cc.Ctid = 200
```

Comment: Did you actually check the manual? If so, what did it say and what did you understand from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for MySQL and MariaDB:

```
update admin.ConfigSupplemental cs join
       admin.Config cc
       on cs.ConsoleConfigID = cc.ID 
    set Value = '20934820843'
where cs.Name = 'GetTime' and cc.Ctid = 200;
```

You can add in the `ignore` if you really intend it.

Comment: Would adding ignore statement after update work? I am in the train right now. And i would like to accept this answeer if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cs alias after ignore and (from) table name in wrong position 
and from in update is not present.

Could be this way

```
 update IGNORE 
 admin.ConfigSupplemental as cs        
 inner join admin.Config as cc on ( cs.ConsoleConfigID = cc.ID  and cs.Name = 'GetTime' and cc.Ctid = 200)
 set Value = '20934820843'
 ;
```